How to remove world background in Eevee reflection plane
I am rendering using Eevee engine, I have a plane with a Glossy BSDF with roughness set to 0. I have selected Film->Transparent in my render properties. When I render this, the plane shows a reflection of the world background. I expected this to render the plane as transparent, showing only the objects in the scene. How can I remove the world background from the reflection?


The Glossy BSDF won't render as transparent if that's what you want. The scene does render without the world background image here though although it will still show in the Render preview unless you have Scene World checked on the Viewport shading menu.

At the end of the day all I want is a mirror. The mirror shouldnt reflect the world background. The attached photo is the final render, you may have to open it in a photo editing program to see the transparency.

You can't add images into comments or attach them for that matter. You'd have to edit your question and add it into that. It's approaching 1am here so I'm going offline now.
